# What is the empty statement in Golang?

Tags: go

In Python we can use `pass` clause as an placeholder.
What is the equivalent clause in Golang?
An `;` or something else?

Comment: The `pass` Keyword in Python is something special that is not needed in most programming languages. It is a side-effect of indentation used to structure the code. In Go empty statements stands for itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Empty statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Empty_statements)
>
> The empty statement does nothing.
>
> EmptyStmt = .
>
> [Notation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Notation)
>
> The syntax is specified using Extended Backus-Naur Form (EBNF):
>
> ```
> Production  = production_name "=" [ Expression ] "." .
> Expression  = Alternative { "|" Alternative } .
> Alternative = Term { Term } .
> Term        = production_name | token [ "…" token ] | Group | Option | Repetition .
> Group       = "(" Expression ")" .
> Option      = "[" Expression "]" .
> Repetition  = "{" Expression "}" .
> ```
>
> Productions are expressions constructed from terms and the following
>   operators, in increasing precedence:
>
> ```
> |   alternation
> ()  grouping
> []  option (0 or 1 times)
> {}  repetition (0 to n times)
> ```
>
> Lower-case production names are used to identify lexical tokens.
>   Non-terminals are in CamelCase. Lexical tokens are enclosed in double
>   quotes "" or back quotes ``.
>
> The form a … b represents the set of characters from a through b as
>   alternatives. The horizontal ellipsis … is also used elsewhere in the
>   spec to informally denote various enumerations or code snippets that
>   are not further specified. The character … (as opposed to the three
>   characters ...) is not a token of the Go language.

The empty statement is empty. In EBNF ([Extended Backus–Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)) form: `EmptyStmt = .` or an empty string.

For example,

```
for {
}

var no
if true {
} else {
    no = true
}
```

Comment: can you make an example about `EmptyStmt = .` means. I.e., what is the meaning about the tailing dot. :)

Comment: that's the answer. :)